# Add elements of NSMutableArray at index with corresponding elements of other NSMutableArrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

If I have 3 NSMutableArray's, how can I get an array where the element at each index is the sum of the elements at that same index in each of the original arrays?

Example:

```
MutableArrayOne  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

MutableArrayTwo  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

MutableArrayThree  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
```

How do I sum them to an array like:

```
MutableArrayThree  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"3",@"6",@"9",@"12",@"15", nil];
```

Comment: May I ask why it is a mutable array?

Comment: Cause there's other coding before that.. that have to use NSMutableArray

Comment: Well, you have a slight problem since you have strings rather than numbers in the arrays.  But otherwise this is trivial -- a simple loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all arrays are of the same size...

```
NSMutableArray *sums = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:MutableArrayOne.count];
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < MutableArrayOne.count; i++)
{
    NSInteger element1 = [[MutableArrayOne objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
    NSInteger element2 = [[MutableArrayTwo objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
    NSInteger element3 = [[MutableArrayThree objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
    NSInteger sum = element1 + element2 + element3;
    [sums addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", sum]];
}
```

Comment: [`NSInteger` is supposed to be cast as long](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), the `%lu` specifier is correct.